# Hello, I'd like some help so that I can use this for loop

Tags: c, for-loop

I don't know how to print something twice using a for loop, however, I know it's possible. Can someone tell me how? I wrote a program trying to print the number "1977" twice by using a for loop. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n;

    for (n = 1976; n < 1978; n++) {
        printf("%d\n", n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try `for(n = 0; n < 2; n++) { ... }` and fill-in the blanks.

Comment: Or, just to be silly, `for (n = 3954; n < 3956; n++) { printf("%d\n", n / 2); }`.

Comment: ```for (n = 1976; n < 1978; n++) {
        printf("%d %d\n", n, n);
}```

Comment: can you clearly explain what do you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @SébastienBémelmans I clearly explained it in the description. I'm trying to print 1977 twice.

Comment: Why do you want to use a loop to print the same thing twice ??  Just go with printf("1977");printf("1977");, this will do the trick... But it's unclear about what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm with Sebastien.  Why are you using a `for` loop at all?

Comment: Because I'm obviously a beginner at C, and I wanted to know how to print something multiple times using a for loop...?

Comment: For what it's worth, that was clear to me.

Comment: That was unclear because he uses the iterator from the loop to print the 1977... So maybe it was useful in a way, but dark on the final goal.

Answer (score 0):

The function you wrote will print:

```
1976
1977
```

Why? The first time through the loop, the value of **n** is **1976**, and you print that. The second time, the value of **n** was been incremented to **1977**, and you print that.

If you want to print **1977** twice, you would want something more like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n;

    for (n = 0; n < 2; n++) {
        printf("1977\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

That should print this:

```
1977
1977
```

Comment: This answered my question! Thank you. It prints 1977.

Answer (score 0):

To confirm, your question is how to print all numbers once and print 1977 twice?

You can check if n is 1977 and do 2nd print statement, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n;

    for (n = 1976; n < 1978; n++) {
        printf("%d\n", n);
        if (n==1977){
            printf("%d\n", n);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @EffZero — Did this answer your question?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thanks.